# PM2 with NodeJS crash after few minutes and restart in loop

Tags: node.js, vps, pm2

I have a NodeJs+Express+Mongodb app and I'm trying to run it on my vps.
I do :

```
pm2 start server

[PM2] Applying action restartProcessId on app [server](ids: [ 1 ])
[PM2] [server](1) ✓
[PM2] Process successfully started
┌────┬────────────────────┬──────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id │ name               │ mode     │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ memory   │
├────┼────────────────────┼──────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 1  │ server             │ fork     │ 991  │ online    │ 0%       │ 13.8mb   │
└────┴────────────────────┴──────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
Current process list running is not in sync with saved list. App app differs. Type 'pm2 save' to synchronize.
```

Everything works fine. But after few minutes pm2 has an error and restart in loop every 1 second :

```
2021-04-21T09:39:19: PM2 log: ===============================================================================
2021-04-21T09:39:19: PM2 log: --- New PM2 Daemon started ----------------------------------------------------
2021-04-21T09:39:19: PM2 log: Time                 : Wed Apr 21 2021 09:39:19 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
2021-04-21T09:39:19: PM2 log: PM2 version          : 4.5.5
2021-04-21T09:39:19: PM2 log: Node.js version      : 15.12.0
2021-04-21T09:39:19: PM2 log: Current arch         : x64
2021-04-21T09:39:19: PM2 log: PM2 home             : /home/debian/.pm2
2021-04-21T09:39:19: PM2 log: PM2 PID file         : /home/debian/.pm2/pm2.pid
2021-04-21T09:39:19: PM2 log: RPC socket file      : /home/debian/.pm2/rpc.sock
2021-04-21T09:39:19: PM2 log: BUS socket file      : /home/debian/.pm2/pub.sock
2021-04-21T09:39:19: PM2 log: Application log path : /home/debian/.pm2/logs
2021-04-21T09:39:19: PM2 log: Worker Interval      : 30000
2021-04-21T09:39:19: PM2 log: Process dump file    : /home/debian/.pm2/dump.pm2
2021-04-21T09:39:19: PM2 log: Concurrent actions   : 2
2021-04-21T09:39:19: PM2 log: SIGTERM timeout      : 1600
2021-04-21T09:39:19: PM2 log: ===============================================================================
2021-04-21T09:39:32: PM2 error: 2 : id unknown
2021-04-21T09:39:32: PM2 error: Trace: Error: 2 : id unknown
    at Object.God.logAndGenerateError (/home/debian/.nvm/versions/node/v15.12.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/God/Methods.js:39:12)
    at Object.God.stopProcessId (/home/debian/.nvm/versions/node/v15.12.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/God/ActionMethods.js:306:21)
    at God.deleteProcessId (/home/debian/.nvm/versions/node/v15.12.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/God/ActionMethods.js:383:9)
    at Server.onmessage (/home/debian/.nvm/versions/node/v15.12.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/pm2-axon-rpc/lib/server.js:104:6)
    at RepSocket.emit (node:events:369:20)
    at RepSocket.emit (node:domain:470:12)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (/home/debian/.nvm/versions/node/v15.12.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/pm2-axon/lib/sockets/rep.js:51:15)
    at Parser.emit (node:events:369:20)
    at Parser.emit (node:domain:532:15)
    at Parser._write (/home/debian/.nvm/versions/node/v15.12.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/amp/lib/stream.js:91:16)
    at Object.God.logAndGenerateError (/home/debian/.nvm/versions/node/v15.12.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/God/Methods.js:34:15)
    at /home/debian/.nvm/versions/node/v15.12.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/God/ActionMethods.js:384:30
    at Object.God.stopProcessId (/home/debian/.nvm/versions/node/v15.12.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/God/ActionMethods.js:306:14)
    at God.deleteProcessId (/home/debian/.nvm/versions/node/v15.12.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/God/ActionMethods.js:383:9)
    at Server.onmessage (/home/debian/.nvm/versions/node/v15.12.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/pm2-axon-rpc/lib/server.js:104:6)
    at RepSocket.emit (node:events:369:20)
    at RepSocket.emit (node:domain:470:12)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (/home/debian/.nvm/versions/node/v15.12.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/pm2-axon/lib/sockets/rep.js:51:15)
    at Parser.emit (node:events:369:20)
    at Parser.emit (node:domain:532:15)
2021-04-21T09:39:49: PM2 log: PM2 successfully stopped
2021-04-21T09:39:57: PM2 log: ===============================================================================
2021-04-21T09:39:57: PM2 log: --- New PM2 Daemon started ----------------------------------------------------
2021-04-21T09:39:57: PM2 log: Time                 : Wed Apr 21 2021 09:39:57 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
2021-04-21T09:39:57: PM2 log: PM2 version          : 4.5.5
2021-04-21T09:39:57: PM2 log: Node.js version      : 15.12.0
2021-04-21T09:39:57: PM2 log: Current arch         : x64
2021-04-21T09:39:57: PM2 log: PM2 home             : /home/debian/.pm2
2021-04-21T09:39:57: PM2 log: PM2 PID file         : /home/debian/.pm2/pm2.pid
2021-04-21T09:39:57: PM2 log: RPC socket file      : /home/debian/.pm2/rpc.sock
2021-04-21T09:39:57: PM2 log: BUS socket file      : /home/debian/.pm2/pub.sock
2021-04-21T09:39:57: PM2 log: Application log path : /home/debian/.pm2/logs
2021-04-21T09:39:57: PM2 log: Worker Interval      : 30000
2021-04-21T09:39:57: PM2 log: Process dump file    : /home/debian/.pm2/dump.pm2
2021-04-21T09:39:57: PM2 log: Concurrent actions   : 2
2021-04-21T09:39:57: PM2 log: SIGTERM timeout      : 1600
2021-04-21T09:39:57: PM2 log: ===============================================================================
2021-04-21T10:07:24: PM2 log: App [app:0] starting in -fork mode-
2021-04-21T10:07:24: PM2 log: App [app:0] online
2021-04-21T10:07:25: PM2 log: App [app:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2021-04-21T10:07:25: PM2 log: App [app:0] starting in -fork mode-
2021-04-21T10:07:25: PM2 log: App [app:0] online
2021-04-21T10:07:26: PM2 log: App [app:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2021-04-21T10:07:26: PM2 log: App [app:0] starting in -fork mode-
2021-04-21T10:07:26: PM2 log: App [app:0] online
2021-04-21T10:07:26: PM2 log: App [app:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2021-04-21T10:07:26: PM2 log: App [app:0] starting in -fork mode-
2021-04-21T10:07:26: PM2 log: App [app:0] online

// infinite loop here

2021-04-21T10:07:27: PM2 log: App [app:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2021-04-21T10:07:27: PM2 log: App [app:0] starting in -fork mode-
2021-04-21T10:07:27: PM2 log: App [app:0] online
```

Can someone help me to understand what's wrong ? Everything works fine in localhost but make it works in production is very hard for me.

Answer (score 1):

how about this?

```
pm2 kill
rm -rf ~/.pm2
```

[found pm2 github](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/4632)

Answer (score 0):

Try and start your app without PM2, usually this indicates the node instance is failing so doing a regular node [appname] will generate where your node app is failing, probably a missing package.

Answer (score 0):

Read the message: the running process is not synchronized.

You need to `pm2 save`.

Follow the appropriate documentation.